# C# cast Type to generic strong typed

Tags: c#, generics, dynamic, reflection, casting

I'm enumerating my EntityFramework Container properties. Through reflection I get only `DbSet` properties. Now I need to access the property value and I tried it this way:

```
object obj = PropertyInfo.GetValue(myobject)
```

All right here but I need to cast to its real type (I ideally need this):

```
DbSet<MyRealType> obj = ( DbSet<MyRealType> )PropertyInfo.GetValue(myobject);
```

But `MyRealType` is unknown at compile time. I only get a `Type` but i can cast it to 
`DbSet<MyrealType>`. Is it possible to achieve that?

Comment: Please add the language tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this is going to be impossible. What you're attempting to do is convert a run time type into a compile time type, and many a programmer has attempted and failed to do so. Your options at this point will mostly involve inspecting the type with reflection and attempting to invoke methods and properties off that guy via reflection as well.

Your other option is to cast the value as `dynamic`, and then attempt (and hope) your invocations work as expected.

So in your situation, you best bet would be to probably use the dynamic type:

```
dynamic obj = Propertyinfo.GetValue(myobject);
obj.SomeMethodYouWantToCall(); // and catch DLR errors
```

Comment: I tried the dynamic way out but it seems like Extension Methods won't be called (actually it seems quite obvious). Thank you anyway.

Comment: You can still invoke extension methods off a dynamic object, it's just more work. IE: `EnumerableExtensions.Select(obj, x => x.SomeProperty)` for what would normally be `obj.Select(x => x.SomeProperty)`. Extension methods ARE just syntactic sugar =D